# Button not visible in android activity

Tags: android, xml

The button in the following xml code is not visible at all. Could someone please guide me where I am going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:text="Add New Item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addItems"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The oncreate() is as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.abc, listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Please include onCreate() code. Do you have setContentView() ?

Comment: is it not visible in the activity? pls post the activity code, as an independent xml, that works fine

Comment: It seems that someone forgot to add **setContentView(R.layout.yourContainer);** in his onCreate...

Comment: I am actually trying to run my ListAdapter. If i include setContentView, it creates problems and the app crashes

Comment: setContentView never create problems for ListAdapter or else either. Instead you should ask for what errors you are getting when you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After super and before "`adapter...`" , call this in onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Calling the `setContentView()`...

```
         // We'll define a custom screen layout here (the one shown above), but
         // typically, you could just use the standard ListActivity layout.
         setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_activity_view);
```

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Also, think your list items which is being passed to the adapter is null (have u checked that?)

Comment: what about the layout abc used in ListAdapter? If i add what you told, the button click crashes the app.

Comment: Post your log fr the crash

Answer (score 0):

**Try it-**

```
  ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.abc, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Probably, you haven't set the layout for your view. So not only the button but the complete view is not visible. For clarity, you can add anything in your view and it will not be displayed at all.

Also please note that if the above is not the case, then see if you have set the visibility to invisible or gone somewhere in your code.

This is only the programming issue as the xml file that you provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You forget setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); //Add this line
      adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main, listItems);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
     }
```